# I can't login in my laravel application

Tags: php, connection, database, vagrant, phpmyadmin

So I was working with a **Laravel** application and something went wrong, so I wanted to charge an early backup version of it. The application is from the company I'm currently working for and I was surprised the employees before me didn't have any git repositories or anything, so I had to literally copy an old project. Now I have a problem with the login part: it simply doesn't work.

Once I enter the username and password, nothing happens and the page refresh. I've already comprobed that the database (with the users) exists and is working correctly via commands. It's important to say that the project is entirely hosted on a **Vagrant** VM which I connect via WinSCP.

I suspect there's a problem with the login-database connection part, but I don't know what it is. I'm kind of a newbie here.

Btw, the app is the intranet of the company. I didn't ruin the original but the developer version, anyways I need to fix it and I'm a little desperate.

Here's the `.env` file. Instead of the pass, i'll put "password" bc company.

```
/*DELETED FOR COMPANY ISSUES*/
```

The `/config/database.php` file:

```
/*DELETED FOR COMPANY ISSUES*/
```

The `login.blade.php` file:

```
/*DELETED FOR COMPANY ISSUES*/
```

And a part of the `web.php` file, the file used for routes:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('admin');
});
Route::group( ['middleware' => ['prevent-back']], function() {

    Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
    Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

    Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin');
});


Route::group( ['middleware' => ['auth','prevent-back']], function() {

    Route::post('admin/changeuser/{user}', 'AdminController@changeLoggedUser')->name('admin.changeuser');    

    Route::post('notification/readall','NotificationController@doReadAll');    
    Route::get('notification/unread','NotificationController@getUnread');
    Route::post('notification/{notification}/read','NotificationController@doRead');
```

---

**EDIT**: I've found some more info that (maybe?) could be useful. I screenshoted the info Laravel told me via browser.

[image]

[image]

---

**EDIT2**: Following the instructions I discovered that my ADLDAP server is not working properly. Once I try to `composer require adldap2/adldap2-laravel` it tries to install but says this:

[image]

I also tried to use [Tinker](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#tinker) to search for the users and stuff. I can see the users using `App/Models/User:all();` but it won't work if I try something like this:

[image]

Apparently the *bind* doesn't work. I'm not very familiarized with it but here's the fragment of code that is not working:

```
public function bind($username, $password, $sasl = false)
{
    if ($this->isUsingTLS()) {
        $this->startTLS();
    }

    if ($sasl) {
        return $this->bound = ldap_sasl_bind($this->getConnection(), null, null, 'GSSAPI');
    }

    return $this->bound = ldap_bind($this->getConnection(), $username, $password);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm suspecting you are using laravel 6, currently Adldap2 isn't fully supported in laravel 6, try using lower version e.g version 5.7 supports the installation of Adlap2.

If that's not the case then navigate to **config** directory then open **auth.php** scroll to ***providers*** and ensure the active driver is either **eloquent** or **database** and not ldap

```
 'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        //REMOVE THIS 'driver' => 'ldap',
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
        'table' => 'users',
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

"Once I enter the username and password, nothing happens and the page refresh" sounds like a redirect loop.

Verify that all of your redirects are correct

- check out your `LoginController`

it might have the following property

```
protected $redirectTo = '/';
```

make sure it is redirected to the correct url

- in the following lines in your`web.php`

  ```
  Route::get('/', function () {
      return redirect('admin');
  });
  ```

try not to `redirect('admin')`, but just echo some text to verify that everything executed before this step works

- you might as well have a problem answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30126451/2510628)

---

Regarding your update.

It seems that your Laravel installation uses [Adldap2/Adldap2-Laravel](https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2-Laravel).

- Do you have LDAP server installed?
- Are privileged users (used for Laravel authentication) added to LDAP
  server?
- Are you able to query ldap server from terminal successfully?
- try to query LDAP server from Laravel as described [here](https://adldap2.github.io/Adldap2-Laravel/#/?id=quick-start)

For example, change the following commands accordingly:

```
    // Finding a user:
    $user = Adldap::search()->users()->find('john doe');

    // Searching for a user:
    $search = Adldap::search()->where('cn', '=', 'John Doe')->get();
```

and see if this gives you an error OR $user contains NULL OR $user contains expected result.

---

UPDATE 2

Are you sure that Authentication in your Laravel application is done through the MySQL DB and not through LDAP server?

When you run `App/Models/User:all();` - you connect through the MySQL DB, but in your "EDIT:" the error says "Can't contact LDAP server".

In Laravel it is possible to authenticate admin account **either** through MySQL **or** LDAP (among many other methods). Your Laravel installation currently tries to make authentication not through MySQL, but through LDAP server. It seems that LDAP server does NOT exist.

Test, if you have LDAP server by trying to connect to it from command line (not from Laravel). [How to test a LDAP connection from a client](https://serverfault.com/a/452940/270580) Then, check if it has an admin user added on that server.

Otherwise, if you are 100% sure that your Laravel admin account authentication is done through the MySQL DB (the admin account with its password is stored there), you have to remove `adldap2/adldap2-laravel` package from Laravel and configure Laravel not to use LDAP authentication.

**Important!** Be sure to use git or some other version control system just not to make things even worse!

If you are not 100% sure whether Laravel auth is done through MySQL or LDAP, I would not remove `adldap2/adldap2-laravel` package, because presumably somebody added it to Laravel installation before you and your current Laravel setup is trying to authenticate through LDAP. So first try to connect to LDAP server by logging in to Vagrant and trying to connect to it from the command line. [How to test a LDAP connection from a client](https://serverfault.com/a/452940/270580) OR [Simple way to check ldap (AD) is running](https://serverfault.com/q/898221/270580) OR using telnet as in this [comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/898221/simple-way-to-check-ldap-ad-is-running#comment1161044_898228)

Comment: I tried everything you said and nothing worked. I think that it's not a problem o redirecting but connection with the database.

My `LoginController` :
`protected $redirectTo = '/admin';`

Also, the echo you suggested in the `web.php` doesn't work. I think we came upon something here.

Comment: verify: 1) LDAP server installation, 2) LDAP server authentication, 3) Laravel configuration for LDAP server, 4) query to LDAP returns expected result

Comment: thank you for your help, I think we could be approaching the issue. I updated the post with more info.

Comment: answer updated.